# No sé por qué el código me funciona como subrutina y no como función

Tags: funciones, vba

Me pidieron hacer una función en Visual Basic que tome un ID que entra por parámetro, lo busque en una base de datos y me devuelva una fecha. Luego tengo que coger esa fecha, dividirla por unidad de tiempo (días, meses y años) y convertirlo todo a un solo dígito y sumar (si tienen más de un dígito, sumarlos entre sí hasta que la suma me de un número menor a 10). Luego tengo que hacer eso mismo con otra fecha especificada anteriormente, comparar ambas sumas y dividir la menor con la mayor. Hice un código primero como subrutina (para ir monitoreando las variables con depuración y la ventana de locales) y todo salió bien, pero al usar el mismo código como función no me salían los mismos valores y hasta me saca errores. No tengo ni idea de lo que pasa y apreciaría mucho cualquier aporte, muchas gracias de antemano.

```
Function compatibilidadSN(id As Long) As Variant

Hoja1.Activate
Dim rango As Range
Set rango = Range("a2").End(xlDown)
For Each i In rango
    If Cells(i, 1) = id Then
        fn2 = Cells(i, 17)
    End If
Next i
fn1 = Hoja2.Cells(21, 16)
dn1 = Day(fn1)
mn1 = Month(fn1)
yn1 = Year(fn1)
dn2 = Day(fn2)
mn2 = Month(fn2)
yn2 = Year(fn2)
While dn1 >= 10
    If dn1 / 10 >= 1 And dn1 / 10 < 2 Then
        If dn1 - 10 > 0 Then
            dn1 = 1 + (dn1 - 10)
        Else
            dn1 = 1
        End If
    ElseIf dn1 / 10 >= 2 And dn1 / 10 < 3 Then
        If dn1 - 20 > 0 Then
            dn1 = 2 + (dn1 - 20)
        Else
            dn1 = 2
        End If
    ElseIf dn1 / 10 >= 3 Then
        If dn1 - 30 > 0 Then
            dn1 = 3 + (dn1 - 30)
        Else
            dn1 = 3
        End If
    End If
Wend
While dn2 >= 10
    If dn2 / 10 >= 1 And dn2 / 10 < 2 Then
        If dn2 - 10 > 0 Then
            dn2 = 1 + (dn2 - 10)
        Else
            dn2 = 1
        End If
    ElseIf dn2 / 10 >= 2 And dn2 / 10 < 3 Then
        If dnl - 20 > 0 Then
            dn2 = 2 + (dn2 - 20)
        Else
            dn2 = 2
        End If
    ElseIf dn2 / 10 >= 3 Then
        If dn2 - 30 > 0 Then
            dn2 = 3 + (dn2 - 30)
        Else
            dn2 = 3
        End If
    End If
Wend
If mn1 / 10 >= 1 Then
    If mn1 - 10 > 0 Then
        mn1 = 1 + (mn1 - 10)
    Else
        mn1 = 1
    End If
End If
If mn2 / 10 >= 1 Then
    If mn2 - 10 > 0 Then
        mn2 = 1 + (mn2 - 10)
    Else
        mn2 = 1
    End If
End If
For i = 4 To 1 Step -1
    xp = 10 ^ i
    par1 = par1 + (yn1 \ xp)
    yn1 = yn1 - ((yn1 \ xp) * xp)
    par2 = par2 + (yn2 \ xp)
    yn2 = yn2 - ((yn2 \ xp) * xp)
Next i
yn1 = par1
yn2 = par2
While yn1 >= 10
    If yn1 / 10 >= 1 And yn1 / 10 < 2 Then
        If yn1 - 10 > 0 Then
            yn1 = 1 + (yn1 - 10)
        Else
            yn1 = 1
        End If
    ElseIf yn1 / 10 >= 2 Then
        If yn1 - 20 > 0 Then
            yn1 = 2 + (yn1 - 20)
        Else
            yn1 = 2
        End If
    End If
Wend
While yn2 >= 10
    If yn2 / 10 >= 1 And yn2 / 10 < 2 Then
        If yn2 - 10 > 0 Then
            yn2 = 1 + (yn2 - 10)
        Else
            yn2 = 1
        End If
    ElseIf yn2 / 10 >= 2 Then
        If yn2 - 20 > 0 Then
            yn2 = 2 + (yn2 - 20)
        Else
            yn2 = 2
        End If
    End If
Wend
ruta1 = dn1 + mn1 + yn1
ruta2 = dn2 + mn2 + yn2
If ruta1 >= 10 And Not (ruta1 = 11 Or ruta1 = 22) Then
    While ruta1 >= 10
        If ruta1 / 10 >= 1 And ruta1 / 10 < 2 Then
        If ruta1 - 10 > 0 Then
            ruta1 = 1 + (ruta1 - 10)
        Else
            ruta1 = 1
        End If
    ElseIf ruta1 / 10 >= 2 Then
        If ruta1 - 20 > 0 Then
            ruta1 = 2 + (ruta1 - 20)
        Else
            ruta1 = 2
        End If
    End If
    Wend
End If
If ruta2 >= 10 And Not (ruta2 = 11 Or ruta2 = 22) Then
    While ruta2 >= 10
        If ruta2 / 10 >= 1 And ruta2 / 10 < 2 Then
        If ruta2 - 10 > 0 Then
            ruta2 = 1 + (ruta2 - 10)
        Else
            ruta2 = 1
        End If
    ElseIf ruta2 / 10 >= 2 Then
        If ruta2 - 20 > 0 Then
            ruta2 = 2 + (ruta2 - 20)
        Else
            ruta2 = 2
        End If
    End If
    Wend
End If
If ruta1 > ruta2 Then
    con = ruta2 / ruta1
Else
    con = ruta1 / ruta2
End If
    compatibilidadSN = con

End Function
```

Comment: Creo que debería ser `End While`, no `Wend`

Comment: ¿Quieres decir que si lo invocas como función te falla y como subrutina no? Un saludo

Comment: @JakintsuIheslari Exactamente, creo que el problema radica cuando intento obtener fn2 (cosa que se me hace rarísima)

Comment: Pues a mi me pasaba lo mismo. Creo que al tratarse de una función, te devuelve algo. Y ese algo debes guardarlo como una variable. Yo hice eso con una función booleana (almacenarla en una variable) y el problema se solucionó. Prueba a ver. Un saludo y gracias por contestar